# jQuery/JS contain operator or similar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element which has many data types, for example:

```
<div class="marker" data-type="industry context history society" data-lat="53.411028" data-lng="-1.4152860" id="1023"></div>
```

And I have this little bit of jQuery/JS that if the data type is a certain 'word' it changes the colour of the marker, for example:

```
if ($marker.data('type') == 'context') {
    icon = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png';
} else {
    icon = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png';
}
```

However, this only works if there is only one 'data-type' word. Is it possible to write this so if the data-type contains the word it will change the icon? I thought there might've been an operator for this but alas there doesn't seem to be.

Comment: What if you put the data type in the class name? Then you could use `$marker.hasClass('context')`.

Comment: `$('.marker[data-type~=context]')` should match the required element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can search for the word like this

```
if ($marker.data('type').indexOf('context') != -1 ) {
    icon = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png';
} else {
    icon = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png';
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
$marker = $(".marker");

if ($marker.data('type').indexOf('context') != -1 ) {
    $marker.css({'color':"blue"}).text( $marker.text()+" context found");
} else {
    $marker.css({'color':"red"}).text( $marker.text()+" context not found");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="marker" 
 data-type="industry context history society" 
 data-lat="53.411028" data-lng="-1.4152860" id="1023">abc</div>
```

Comment: might fail for attribute values like `contextfree something`.

Comment: @Sirko Well OP didn't mention that he wants to match the word `context` in a conjugated form... plus this would work anyway, because it's simply searching for the string `context`, not matching any word boundaries.

Comment: word means separted by spaces i think @Sirko not sure

Comment: Thanks for this... for some reason this doesn't seem to work?

Comment: @sirko " a contextof a b c".indexOf("context") is 3

Comment: @braw what problem you are facing after using this

Comment: I think the saver approach would be `$marker.data('type').split(' ').indexOf('context')`. Just to prevent false positives.

Comment: @A.B It doesn't change the icon to green dot. Could we use .is() here? Or...?

Comment: @braw see the demo it is working for the match, may be some other problem

Comment: @Sirko i think "contextfree something".indexOf("context") will still not be -1. was thinking to update the answer but it wont make difference

Comment: @A.B Indeed it was ;) many thanks for the help, this makes sense and will remember going forward.